# Maven: missing net.sf.json-lib

Tags: maven-2

I found net.sf.json-lib [in the central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib). Copy-pasted the dependency (with version 2.3), and then when I build I get this error:

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.2.3' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.3

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
```

I tried using version 2.2.3, but I'm getting the same error. Why am I getting this error? I can override it by installing it locally, but I want to understand what the problem is.

**Edit** - I deleted the package from my local repository, and tried again, this time getting a checksum error. I guess I should file a bug report with json-lib.

```
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Error retrieving checksum file for net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.3/json
-lib-2.3.pom - IGNORING
```

Comment: It looks like the file in maven central has a incorrect checksum...you must decide if you trust it anyway or don't.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Looking at the [maven-central repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/), you need to specify a classifier for this dependency.

Either jdk13 or jdk15, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. In `BuildConfig.groovy`, I do: `dependencies { 
   runtime group:'net.sf.json-lib', name:'json-lib', version:'2.4',
           classifier:'jdk15' 
}`
but to no avail. I get `Failed to resolve dependency.`. 
Any idea why ?

Comment: Right.  It doesn't help that http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.json-lib%7Cjson-lib%7C2.4%7Cjar  is lying to us, and omitting the classifier.

Comment: FYI, for those using Play Framework 1.x, you can't use this jar from maven central - https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/986-support-for-classifier-in-dependenciesyml#ticket-986-3

Comment: Nice! Wonder why the classifier wasn't set when I initially added the dependency that had jdk15.

Comment: What's the equivalent for ivy?

Comment: I got following error, Could not find artifact net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:2.4 in wso2-nexus (http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/). Onces add "<classifier>jdk15</classifier>" this line additionally, this build working without any issue. Thanks lot

Comment: hello, thx for the answer. question: how did you know about the classfier ?

Answer (score 28):

For gradle as sample

> compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15'

OR

> compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version: '2.4', classifier: 'jdk15'

I searched for more classifier's could not find anything other than jdk15 (don't go looking or jdk16 or jdk17)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to install the file locally similar to @icyrock.com's suggestion, then put `mavenLocal()` before `mavenCentral()` in the `repositories` sections.

Comment: Just for documentation: there is at least one [bug in Gradle](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3188) associated with transitive dependencies, also as far as I can tell, json-lib doesn't supply any classifier data in its POM (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092085/building-same-project-in-maven-with-different-artifactid-based-on-jdk-used) and [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|net.sf.json-lib|json-lib|2.2.3|jar)). I also couldn't find a way to determine whether Gradle checks for checksum errors as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Barring khimarbaise's comment about trustworthiness, you can install it locally using maven install:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html

> ```
> mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar
>                           -DgroupId=your.groupId
>                           -DartifactId=your-artifactId
>                           -Dversion=version
>                           -Dpackaging=jar
>                           -DlocalRepositoryPath=path-to-specific-local-repo
> ```

Comment: I already had the jar file (I'm convering the project to maven), so I installed what I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For ivy users, after trying many different iterations to configure my ivy.xml to properly find this dependency, this finally worked for me:

> ```
>   <dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" name="json-lib" rev="2.4">
>         <artifact name="json-lib" url="http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar"/>     
>     </dependency>
> ```

Comment: I think the hardwired URL is not an optimal solution, this works in Ivy too:

 <dependency org="net.sf.json-lib" name="json-lib" rev="2.3">
  <artifact name="json-lib" 
                maven:classifier="jdk15" 
                type="jar" ext="jar"/>
 </dependency>

Comment: @stumbav, this doesn't work for me. It gives error: parsed: [[Fatal Error] ivy.xml:19:137: The prefix "maven" for attribute "maven:classifier" associated with an element type "artifact" is not bound