# Which version of a Maven artifact works for which JVM

Tags: java, maven, jvm

Is there a common way of finding out which version of a Maven artifact is compiled against which Java version?

It always seems to take way too long to

1. Work out that it is a jvm version issue
2. Find out which jvm version the current aritfact uses
3. Track back through the versions of the artifact to find one that works

If there is not a common mechanism, do some artifacts adopt a naming convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard way of naming, using the classifier attribute of an artifact.

[Building same project in Maven with different artifactid (based on JDK used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092085/building-same-project-in-maven-with-different-artifactid-based-on-jdk-used)