# building-same-project-in-maven-with-different-artifactid-based-on-jdk-used for a ear file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

[Building same project in Maven with different artifactid (based on JDK used)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092085/building-same-project-in-maven-with-different-artifactid-based-on-jdk-used)

See this above question which was previously given in StackOverflow.

Can we use different jdk version in ear files?

As in ear files we have so many jar or war files .if we will use the classifier then it is not running the next module as all have dependent to each other.

This above questions answer is not suitable for a ear file so can we improve this question's answer .

Because I am implementing it in  ear file and I can't get the correct answer.

During the run it says this problem

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.3.2:ear (default-ear) on
>   project WebservicesPAMEAR: 
>       Cannot copy a directory: C:*\WebServicePAM\target\classes; 
>       Did you package/install com.*:WebServicePAM:war:
>       1610.0.123-SNAPSHOT:provided? -> [Help 1]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking that'd be good start.

Comment: Thank you sarseth.

Comment: You should give to your question not such a crap title.