# Please help with choosing CI build tool

Tags: java, build, continuous-integration

I need to choose the right CI build tool which will:

1. Support groups of build configurations so we can use the standardized build process for all our projects
2. Support dashboard with "pretty" (for executive/director "eye" :-) reports.
3. Support Java, Maven, Ant, and be somewhat customizable for build process itself (though this is optional, as I can "fix" it with scripts)

I'd prefer *free* and *open source* tool, but paid version is fine too.

Please help :-)

Comment: Hudson or TeamCity. Take a look at them and choose.

Comment: I didn't find any good looking reporting plugins for Hudson. Any suggestions? And Hudson does not support "groups of build configurations", it falls short there. May be there is some special plugin for that, but I can't find it nowhere.

Comment: hudson has "matrix projects" http://stackoverflow.com/q/424295/4279 I don't know whether it is "groups of build configurations" that you need.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). It already has built in support for Maven and Ant.

Comment: See above. Reporting dashboard and Groups of Build Configurations are requirements, but not sure if Hudson meets them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at it

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/company

ThoughtWorks Deployment Management Solution combines the power of

Twist (Agile testing) with Go (release management).

- Twist captures the requirements to be
  tested directly from business users
  and then supports their automation as
  long-term tests that evolve with the
  application. Go helps development and
  IT operations teams model release
  processes and deploy software
  repeatably and reliably.

Answer (score 0):

[Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/) has rather good support for groups and rather straightforward test execution